# Design a relational database so an entity can hold an optional set of data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, orm, relational-database

I am trying to figure out how I can design a database that will allow me to model jobs that multiple departments are involved in.

The job should be able to be 'connected' to different departments, and then I need to be able to store a set of information associated with that department for that job.

For example, a job involving making a sign might involve the graphics department and the printing department. The graphics department may need to be able to upload design concepts and the printing department may need to be able to store materials used.

How can I model this in a relational database in a sane manner I can interact with through an ORM framework (specifically the Eloquent ORM framework)?

Answer (score 0):

A department can have many jobs so this will be a one-to-many unless a job can be associated with many departments as you seem to imply. The job itself would contain the materials/concepts although your resources table could link back to the departments for their ownership. I'd suggest drawing something out on paper first and thinking about which data will go there before you start coding. This will give you an idea of whether it will work or not before you start. Let me know if you have any specific questions.